# Disk array for virtual machines

Tags: virtualization, raid, hyper-v, hard-drive

Is there any recommened array for placing the disks of a virtual infraestrcture.
As example, I heard that for the OS disk is recommened a mirror array. For placing virtual hard dkis which is recommended?

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what you have the VMs doing, in the same way that the array shape that you choose for a non-VM system needs to take into account what the system is doing.

For making that choice for either a VM data store or a physical machine, refer to [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/339128/what-are-the-different-widely-used-raid-levels-and-when-should-i-consider-them).

Comment: I can Understand that I should used the best practice for the role that i'll run on the vm. So, for the virtual disk for Operating System in the VM should I use a mirror?

Comment: @RicardoPolo That usually makes sense for physical machines so that you can dedicate two disks to a smallish OS RAID group, but it's not always what I'd recommend for a VM's OS.  The operating system disk doesn't tend to have high I/O needs in many deployments (though it does in some), so it might not make sense for you to deploy a big group of RAID 10 for your VMs' operating system disks.

Comment: thank you. So what kind of raid should you use? What do you think about a raid 5 for vms?

Comment: RAID5 is almost never a good choice for a production environment, but in any event, you've not given enough information to answer your question.  If you run your VMs off a SAN, you probably don't need RAID at all.  If you've got some other setup, what's going to matter most is how the physical disks on the host are setup.

Comment: @HopelessN00b Why not? In the SAN i should create arrays, isn't it?